# entity_query: sort: Column not found: Unknown column 'membership__field_year.field_year_value'

Tags: 8, entities, database

I am using a entity_query, where I get a fatal error because the sort field is not found. The integer field (*field_year exists*) and exists in the database in the *membership__field_year* table in the *field_year_value* row.

```
query = $this->entity_query->get('membership');
$query->condition('field_membership_member', $this->member->id());
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->sort('field_year' , 'DESC');
```

This is the error I get:

> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'membership__field_year.field_year_value' in 'field list'

How do I sort on an integer field?

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. Apparently I was calling `$query->execute()` twice.